# SQL delete duplicate id combinations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique

So for example this table:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
|   data    | entry1 | entry2 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| id        |      1 |      2 |
| user_id   |      1 |      1 |
| killer_id |      2 |      2 |
| server_id |      6 |      6 |
| score     |    100 |     50 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I have now a lot of entries where `user_id`, `killer_id` and `server_id` are equal and the combination of them should be unique.
I'd like to delete all duplicate entries and just keep the entry with the lowest score.

If I try to make them unique now, I get an Error

`ALTER TABLE kill_server_table ADD UNIQUE unique_index(user_id, killer_id, server_id)`

`Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '277-1834-24' for key 'unique_index'`

How to realize this or is there a better way to make them unique?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the Post

Comment: "the combination of them should be unique" - why don't you have a `UNIQUE` constraint to prevent that from happening in the first place? Or use a composite PK?

Comment: Your sample table doesn't match the `ALTER` statement. There are no columns `user_id`, `killer_id` or `server_id`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the records first:

```
delete t
     from thistable t join
          (select user_id, killer_id, server_id, min(score) as min_score
           from thistable t
           group by user_id, killer_id and server_id
          ) tt
          using (user_id, killer_id, server_id)
    where score > min_score;
```

Then you can add a unique constraint or index.